# Why indexOf() function in React Js is returning in -1 even if the parameter is persent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am implementing filter table in `React Js`, for this I need to search a product name entered by user from my product list. I am taking user input and finding it's index for each product of my product list using `indexOf()` function. If `indexOf()` return -1 then add this product to searched product list, otherwise ignore current product. I test it using an test component and it is working fine.

I went through following question, but it did't worked for me.

[javascript indexOf keeps returning -1 even if the object is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48355889/javascript-indexof-keeps-returning-1-even-if-the-object-is-present)

[Node.js: indexOf returning -1 even though item is in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469915/node-js-indexof-returning-1-even-though-item-is-in-array)

[Object comparison in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

[indexOf method in an object array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668174/indexof-method-in-an-object-array)

My testing component:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div >
                <h1>Filter text: {this.props.filterText}</h1>
                <h2>Product name: {this.props.name}</h2>
                <h3>Test: {this.props.name.indexOf(this.props.filterText)}</h3>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

***Input:***

```js
const filterText='r';
const name='ball';
ReactDOM.render(
  <App filterText={filterText} name={name} />,document.getElementById('hello')
);
```

***Output:***
[image: Output 1]
***Input:***

```js
const filterText='l'; 
const name='ball';
ReactDOM.render(
  <App filterText={filterText} name={name} />,document.getElementById('hello')
);
```

***Output:***
[image]

Same functionality i want to include in my react filter list project. When the same input i am giving then it is returning -1. For simplicity, i rendered all the values on screen.

***My Code:(Component that have logic.***

```js
 class ProductTable extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
        var filterText=this.props.filterText;
        const inStockOnly=this.props.inStockOnly; 
        const row=[];
        let lastCategory=null;
        this.props.product.forEach(function(product){
            row.push(
                <Test filterText={filterText} name={product.name} test={product.name.indexOf(filterText)} />
            );
            if(product.name.indexOf(filterText)===false)
                return;

            if(inStockOnly&&!product.stocked)
                return;

            if(product.category!==lastCategory){
                row.push(
                    <ProductCategoryRow category={product.category} key={product.category}/>
                );
            }
          row.push(
              <ProductRow product={product} key={product.name}/>
          );
          lastCategory=product.category; 
        })

        return(
            <div>
        <h3 className="text-danger">Your Product</h3>
            <ProductCategoryRow category={row}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

***Other component:***

```js
class ProductCategoryRow extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const category=this.props.category;
        return(
            <tr>
                <th colSpan='2' className="text-info">
                    <h1>{category}</h1>
                </th>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}
class ProductRow extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const product=this.props.product;
        const name=product.stocked? product.name: <span style={{color:'red'}}>
            {product.name}
        </span>
        return(
                <tr className='text-warning'>
                     <td><h4>{name}</h4></td>
                     <td> <h4>{product.price}</h4> </td>
                </tr>

        );
    }
}
```

`Test is index of filterText`
***OUTPUT:*** 
**Incorrect:** 
[image] 
**Correct:** 
[image]

Comment: `'b' !== 'B'`. Maybe lowercasing the strings first would help? `name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase())`

Comment: You provided very extensive and even a little of non-relevant content. Your problem is visible in the pictures though. I did not have a look at the code at all. Consider putting the product name and the query string toLowerCase() as "Ball" is capital "B" and lowercase b is not equal. Actually the difference is 32 thus a comparison would return false.

Answer (score 1):

The `indexOf()` method is case-sensitive, that's why you got these results, check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). You can use the [.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) or the [.toUpperCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) function before check with `indexOf()`. You need to use any of them on both of the strings you test.

For example with `.toLowerCase()`, change your code to:

```
test={product.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase())}
```

And

```
if(product.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase())===false)
```

Comment: As you can see my input is already in lower case. But, as you said i replaced `<Test filterText={filterText} name={product.name} test={product.name.indexOf(filterText.)} />` to `<Test filterText={filterText} name={product.name} test={product.name.indexOf(filterText.toLowerCase())} />` and stil having same problem .

Comment: Oh, I mean the name should be lowercase too, editing my answer.

Comment: I think before matching convert `filterText` and `product.name` to either lower or uppercase

Answer (score -1):

You can Try to use includes method in lodash library. This should work.

_.includes(product.name.toLowerCase(), filter.toLowerCase());